# Import-csv Multiple files

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Simple Task. Just trying to loop through a folder of .csv files and import them. I'm a bit confused as this does work on other scripts, but I must be missing something very obvious.

$CSVFiles correctly finds 3 files in the folder.
However $csvOutput only contains data from the last file in the folder.
The rest of the script is working fine.

```
$CSVFolder = 'D:\XXXX\2021_MAY\'
$OutputFile = 'D:\XXXX\2021_MAY\merged_MAY.csv'
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFolder -Filter *.csv

foreach ($csv in $CSVFiles)

{$csvOutput = Import-Csv $csv.FullName
    
    $group = $csvOutput | Select-Object 
    'Channel Reference',
    'Received Date',
    'Currency',
    'Payment Method',
    'Channel Payment Reference',
    'Line Total Excluding Tax',
    'Order Tax','Order Total' | Group-Object {$_.'Channel Reference'} 
    
    $group | Where Count -gt 1 | Foreach-Object 
{
    $_.Group[0].'Line Total Excluding Tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Line Total Excluding Tax' -Sum).Sum
}
     $group | Foreach-Object { $_.Group[0] } | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoType
}
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the output on every iteration. Try `-Append`

Comment: Theo, Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed this

```
$CSVFolder = 'D:\XXXX\2021_MAY\'
$OutputFile = 'D:\XXXX\2021_MAY\merged_MAY.csv'
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFolder -Filter *.csv

foreach ($csv in $CSVFiles){
$group = Import-Csv $csv.FullName | Select-Object 'Channel Reference','Received Date','Currency','Payment Method','Channel Payment Reference','Line Total Excluding Tax','Order Tax','Order Total' | Group-Object {$_.'Channel Reference'} |
 Foreach-Object {
 if ($_.Count -gt 1){
 $_.Group[0].'Line Total Excluding Tax' = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Line Total Excluding Tax' -Sum).Sum
}
$_.Group[0]

}
$group | Export-Csv $OutputFile  -notype -append
}
```